# How to map CRM entities to SQL Server table dynamically?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

How to map CRM entities to SQL Server tables dynamically when sequence of properties are not same using C# ?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish? I'm afraid it isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to get the fields of entities that have been created in CRM and then work with them in your c# application?

If this is the case, then you would need to use the IOrganizationWebService to get a list of entities, their attributes and data types. And then, using this information, interact with them as late-bound entities.

These links should help you get started:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309449.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx